# Compiling shared schema used by 2 WSDL using XMLBeans

Tags: java, xsd, cxf, xmlbeans

I have this following directory structure

```
Root
   CommonSchema
      1.xsd
      2.xsd

   Service1
      XSD
        3.xsd ( importing 1 and 2 xsd )
      WSDL
        A.wsdl ( importing 3.xsd )

   Service2
      XSD
        4.xsd ( importing 1 and 2 xsd )
      WSDL
        B.wsdl ( importing 4.xsd )
```

I'm trying to generate the source and compiling them into a single jar using XMLBeans+CXF. 
CommonSchema folder has schemas that shared by Service1 and 2.

When I try to generate the source source, it seems that the source of 1 and 2 xsd has a naming conflict, that can be seen below :

**First WSDL Generation**

[image]

**Second WSDL Generation**

[image]

Any idea on how should I compile this common schema?

Here is my Ant Script :

```
<target name="cxfWSDLToJava">
  <java classname="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava" fork="true">
    <arg value="-databinding"/>
    <arg value="xmlbeans"/>
    <arg value="-client"/>
    <arg value="-d"/>
    <arg value="cxfsrc"/>
    <arg value="D:\Generation\Services\CBS-CustAccountInfo-I\WSDL\CBS-CustAccountInfo-I-Concrete.wsdl"/>
    <classpath>
      <path refid="cxf.classpath"/>
    </classpath>
  </java>
</target>

<target name="cxfWSDLTXNToJava">
  <java classname="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava" fork="true">
    <arg value="-databinding"/>
    <arg value="xmlbeans"/>
    <arg value="-client"/>
    <arg value="-d"/>
    <arg value="cxfsrc"/>
    <arg value="D:\Generation\Services\CBS-DirectDebCredTransfer-C\WSDL\CBS-DirectDebCredTransfer-C-Concrete.wsdl"/>
    <classpath>
      <path refid="cxf.classpath"/>
    </classpath>
  </java>
</target>
```

my project is located at : [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/chiq6oi5uk91i66/X-OQtVnL91) under CXF-Generation.

the whole schema + WSDL can be found under CXF-Generation/Generation

Comment: Can you post your build script

Comment: Hi, I'm using ant script of wsdl2java. I have updated my question.

Comment: I can't try it right now, but can you or someone else interested in the bounty ;)... try to create another WSDL that sits on top of the two you've listed (use wsdl:import to link those two), and use just that one WSDL in your ant task? It seems that you target the same source folder and classpath, so it should work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an xsdconfig solve my problem. 
In the end I have duplicated package, but it suits my needs.

My Maven to generate the conflicted package

```
<executions>
<execution>
    <id>generate-sources</id>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <configuration>
        <wsdlOptions>
            <wsdlOption>
                <wsdl>${basedir}\..\Generation\Services\CBS-DirectDebCredTransfer-C\WSDL\CBS-DirectDebCredTransfer-C-Concrete.wsdl</wsdl>
                <extraargs>
                    <extraarg>-db</extraarg>
                    <extraarg>xmlbeans</extraarg>
                    <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                    <extraarg>com.xxx.txnpos.ws</extraarg>
                </extraargs>
                <bindingFiles>
                    <bindingFile>${basedir}/txnpos.xsdconfig</bindingFile>
                </bindingFiles>
            </wsdlOption>
        </wsdlOptions>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
</executions>
```

My xsd config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xb:config xmlns:xb="http://xml.apache.org/xmlbeans/2004/02/xbean/config">
<xb:namespace uri="http://schemas.xxx.com/soa/emf/common/aggregates/">
<xb:package>com.xxx.schemas.soa.emf.txnpost.aggregates</xb:package>
</xb:namespace>
<xb:namespace uri="http://schemas.xxx.com/soa/emf/common/body/">
<xb:package>com.xxx.schemas.soa.emf.txnpost.body</xb:package>
</xb:namespace>
<xb:namespace uri="http://schemas.xxx.com/soa/emf/common/elements/">
<xb:package>com.xxx.schemas.soa.emf.txnpost.elements</xb:package>
</xb:namespace>
<xb:namespace uri="http://schemas.xxx.com/soa/emf/common/envelope/">
<xb:package>com.xxx.schemas.soa.emf.txnpost.envelope</xb:package>
</xb:namespace>
<xb:namespace uri="http://schemas.xxx.com/soa/emf/common/header/">
<xb:package>com.xxx.schemas.soa.emf.txnpost.header</xb:package>
</xb:namespace>
<xb:namespace uri="http://schemas.xxx.com/soa/emf/common/monetaryErrorReponse/">
<xb:package>com.xxx.schemas.soa.emf.txnpost.monetaryErrorReponse</xb:package>
</xb:namespace>
</xb:config>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an ant expert so i'm not sure i'm right, but I think the problem is that one target ovverides the other.

When running XmlBeans command if you run it like 2 seperate commands:

```
wsdl2java -uri my_service1.wsdl
wsdl2java -uri my_service2.wsdl
```

The first command will generate a jar and the second one will ovverride it with the a new code from the second wsdl.

I think you are running it like this and that is why you get only the code of one wsdl.

You need to combine them both into one wsdl (maybe a wrapper wsdl) and then generate the code from it.

Or you can generate 2 different jars.

**EDIT:**

A little correction, apparently [only IBM support importing a wsdl from another wsdl](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/cwbs_wsdl.html).

So the wrapper option is off the table. IMHO, these are your options:

1. Change the target namespace of the common schema so there won't be a conflict and generate 2 jars.
2. Combine both wsdls into one (simple copy paste) - might be a bit tricky if there are methods/parameters with same name that have different purpose.

Comment: Hi ftom2, Initially I created 2 jars, however this cause conflict in classpath ( the common schema class generated with different implementation ) if you use it together. Now I wonder if i can generate the 2nd wsdl with different package name on the common schema. For your other suggestion to create wrapper wsdl, may I know how to do that?

Comment: If you can change the target namespace in the wsdl that will generate it with a different package.

Comment: 2nd option resulted in error : Non-unique body parts! In a port, operations must have unique operation signatures on the wire for successful dispatching. In port {http://tempuri.og/myEndPoint.wsdl}Port, operations "{http://tempuri.og/myEndPoint.wsdl}CBS-CustAccountInfo-I" and "{http://tempuri.og/myEndPoint.wsdl}CBS-DirectDebCredTransfer-C" have the same request body block {http://schemas.ocbc.com/soa/emf/common/envelope/}ServiceEnvelope ( This is my initial problem )

Comment: For the first option, the wsdl is actually belong to other party, so the real implementation can't be changed. Do you think this is okay?

Comment: No, the service has to change as well :(, Can you contact the service provider? if changes are to be made to the wsdl, it is best they do it.